# AWS CDK Jest Unit Test Resource Has DeletionPolicy

Tags: jestjs, aws-cdk

In the AWS CDK, I can write a Jest unit test to test if a resource has a specific property. But how do I test a resource DeletionPolicy value which is NOT a property?

cdk.out/example.template.json (simplified)

```
"AppsUserPool8FD9D0C0": {
  "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
  "Properties": {
    "UserPoolName": "test",
    ...
  },
  "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Retain",
  "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
  "Metadata": {}
}
```

Jest unit test passes for property (simplified)

```
expect(stack).toHaveResourceLike('AWS::Cognito::UserPool', {
  "UserPoolName": "test"
});
```

Jest unit test fails for DeletionPolicy (simplified)

```
expect(stack).toHaveResourceLike('AWS::Cognito::UserPool', {
  "DeletionPolicy": "Retain"
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following example
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/775a0c930a680f8a52bb4a40084d07492f7f9fee/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation/test/test.resource.ts#L57

You can use haveResouce() with parameter `ResourcePart.CompleteDefinition`

snippet from the example

```
      expect(stack).to(haveResource('AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource', {
        DeletionPolicy: 'Retain',
        UpdateReplacePolicy: 'Retain',
      }, ResourcePart.CompleteDefinition));
```

Answer (score 9):

Updated snippet for CDK 2.x

```js
const template = Template.fromStack(stack);
template.hasResource('AWS::Cognito::UserPool', {
  DeletionPolicy: 'Retain',
  UpdateReplacePolicy: 'Retain',
});
```

Comment: That worked for me. I was using `hasResourceProperties` before, which was throwing a "Missing key 'DeletionPolicy'" error. `hasResourceProperties` goes directly into the `Properties` attribute, so you won't be able to check for the DeletionPolicy. `hasResource` sets it at the right level

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated snippet confirmed working on CDK version: 1.107.0

```
import { ResourcePart } from '@aws-cdk/assert';

test('stack has correct policies', async () => {
    expect(stack).toHaveResource('AWS::Cognito::UserPool', {
        DeletionPolicy: 'Retain',
        UpdateReplacePolicy: 'Retain',
    }, ResourcePart.CompleteDefinition);
});
```